# rtcwake not waking computer

Tags: server, suspend

Running Ubuntu Server 16.04. I have a cron task that is set to run as the root user to hibernate my machine for a few hours. The script is:

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/sbin/ntpd -q
/sbin/hwclock -w --utc
/usr/sbin/rtcwake -v -m disk -t $(/bin/date +%s -d 'today 09:00')
```

I can tell the script is running correctly because the job shows up in `sudo journalctl | grep CRON`. Also the machine is in a suspended state.

However, the machine never wakes up. This script used to work until I moved the machine to a new case. I thought the issue might be the CMOS battery so I replaced that. I'm not sure if I plugged the SATA drive back into the same port it was in originally. Otherwise the hardware didn't change. Any suggestions what might have caused this?